# PHP work with json stringify object

Tags: javascript, php, json, submit

I have an object in the frontend and need to pass this value to the backend (PHP).

Frontend:

```
var cfg = {"tooltips":true,"tooltipTemplate":"<div></div>"},
jsonCfg = JSON.stringify(cfg);
$inputConfig.val(jsonCfg);
$form.submit();
```

Backend:

```
$config = $_POST['config'];
$json = json_decode($config);
echo $json->tooltips;
echo $json->tooltipTemplate;
```

The last string gives me only empty value, if I remove the first tag "<", I will get only "div>", but I do not understand how to prevent this behavior, I need any string without filtering or formatting.

Comment: `echo $json->tooltipTemplate;` will output `<div></div>`, which won't display in the page output (because it's HTML). View the source and it should be there

Comment: I think you're right, this is my fail I forget about this.

Comment: I would delete the question. It's not got any downvotes so it won't hurt you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is simply, that `<div></div>` isn't visible in the browser. If you want to view the correct output, have a look at the page source or use `htmlentities` to escape the html tags.

```
$config = $_POST['config'];
$json = json_decode($config);
echo $json->tooltips;
echo htmlentities($json->tooltipTemplate);
```

Comment: I've checked it inside network tab, response section. It's ok now, thanks.